# Creating Datagridview in C#.net with our desired behaviours/override the existing behaviours

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls

I'm using `DatagridView` in my project. I have to Add a `DataGridView` in Each form that i created. And in each `form` i have to Add some similar code blocks in this case. Instead of that i want to create a `control library`. In the library i want to implement my own behaviour *(override default behaviour of that contol)* .

Can anybody please help me in this regards? .How to create a custom `Datagridview` *(inherited from the `DatagridVview` provided in .net)* with our own behaviours in c#.net.

Answer (score 0):

A control is just a class.

You can create your own class that inherits from the `DataGridView` control.

You can then override or add different behaviour

```
public class CustomGridView : DataGridView {

   public string MyCustomProperty { get; set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that inherits from the DataGridView and override the behaviours